# Libhand library compilation error using cmake

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, ogre, libhand

I'm trying to build a hand model library from [libhand.org](http://www.libhand.org/) on Ubuntu 12.04. The library uses ogre and opencv libraries. I followed the instructions provided by the author that allowed me to successfully install ogre and opencv. Unfortunately when configuring a libhand library itself using cmake (by command "cmake ..") I get the following error:

> CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but
> they are set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set
> and tested correctly in the CMake files:
> OGRE_RenderSystem_GL_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)    used as include
> directory in directory
> /home/roman/work_dir/libhand-0.9/hand_cpp/source    used as include
> directory in directory
> /home/roman/work_dir/libhand-0.9/hand_cpp/source/dot_sceneloader
> used as include directory in directory
> /home/roman/work_dir/libhand-0.9/hand_cpp/source/dot_sceneloader/tinyxml
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Does anyone know why this error occurs and what can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the [libhand](http://www.libhand.org/) library author and I debugged this problem with Roman. Here's the cause and the fix to this problem:

Cause:

> **The OpenGL developer headers/libraries were not installed** before OGRE was compiled and then installed.

OGRE silently compiles, but without OpenGL support. The code using OGRE then fails to compile because of the missing OpenGL support in OGRE.

---

The **fix** for this issue:

1) Install OpenGL development headers/libraries by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev
```

2) Recompile/reinstall OGRE.

When using [libhand](http://www.libhand.org/), recompiling OGRE means going into the `install_help/linux_ogre_static_installer` directory and running:

```
./install_ogre_static.sh clean
```

followed by

```
./install_ogre_static.sh build
```

and

```
sudo ./install_ogre_static.sh install
```

3) Clean & re-build libhand or other piece of software that reported this error.

For libhand, go to `hand_cpp` and do:

```
rm -rf build/*
```

followed by

```
cd build
cmake ..
```

You should not be seeing the reported error after this step and hopefully libhand will work out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

CMake can't find OpenGL's header files. Install `-dev` package for libGL.